# How to Create Empty Spark DataFrame in PySpark and Append Data?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a task of combining multiple Spark DataFrames generated from a for loop together. So I thought to create an empty DataFrame before running the for loop and then combine them by UnionAll. `result` is the name of data frames generated from for loop.

Below is the code:

```
empty = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD(), StructType([]))
empty = empty.unionAll(result)
```

Below is the error:

```
first table has 0 columns and the second table has 25 columns
```

Looks like I have to specify specific schema when creating the empty Spark DataFrame. I am wondering if there is a way to make it work without doing so or simply combine Spark DataFrames. I do have many columns to specify otherwise.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: does your all dataframes all have different schema?

Comment: they have same schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your `empty` dataframe doesn't has any columns so when we do **`unionAll`** we need to have same number of columns.

Try by creating `empty dataframe` with **`result dataframe schema`** then do **unionAll**.

**`Example:`**

```
result=spark.createDataFrame([(1,2,3,4)],['id','a','b','c'])
empty = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD(), result.schema)
empty.unionAll(result).show()
#+---+---+---+---+
#| id|  a|  b|  c|
#+---+---+---+---+
#|  1|  2|  3|  4|
#+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess this would be the easiest solution giving that 2 data frames have to have same number of columns for appending/unionAll